# « Fâcheux », « malheureux », « triste »,« dégueulasse » ou autre?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

La fille t’a serré dans ses bras  contre ton gré par derrière et une semaine après elle te traîne en justice pour attouchement sexuel. C’est vraiment une situation des plus

…**fâcheuses**, surtout que tu n’as même pas daigner la repousser pour lui être agréable. Tu ne méritais pas ça. Je te souhaite que cette action en justice reste sans effet.

…**malheureuses**, surtout que tu n’as même pas daigner la repousser pour lui être agréable. Tu ne méritais pas ça. Je te souhaite que cette action en justice reste sans effet.

…**tristes**, surtout que tu n’as même pas daigner la repousser pour lui être agréable. Tu ne méritais pas ça. Je te souhaite que cette action en justice reste sans effet.

…**dégueulasses**, surtout que tu n’as même pas daigner la repousser pour lui être agréable. Tu ne méritais pas ça. Je te souhaite que cette action en justice reste sans effet.

Après qu’un ami vous eut dit cela, **qu’auriez-vous pensé et dit?** Je suis ouvert aux reformulations!

Edit**

La fille t’a serré dans ses bras  contre ton gré par derrière et une semaine après elle te traîne en justice pour attouchement sexuel. Il est vraiment fâcheux d’en venir à cette extrémité, d’autant plus que tu n’as fait que subir une étreinte sans la repousser pour lui être agréable. Je te souhaite que cette action en justice reste sans effet.

Comment: Ces formulations recouvrent des niveaux de langage et des degrés d'intensité assez différents. Que cherche-t-on a exprimer ? Quelques mots polis ? Une compassion sincère ? Le dégoût ou la colère ? ...

Comment: Quelques mots polis et une compassion sincère. Qu’auriez-vous dit sur le moment à quelqu’un qui se serait confié à vous en vous racontant ces choses?

Comment: Je cherche à savoir quelle serait la réaction et quels seraient les propos normales à avoir après avoir été mis au courant d’une confidence/information de ce genre.

Comment: "Malheureuses" me parait le niveau approprié, "dégueulasse" étant plus du registre de la colère.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fâcheux est froid et un peu ampoulé. Malheureux convient bien (avec l'idée de la malchance). Triste est un peu hors de propos. Dégueulasse me semble excessif.